# How can I read in a binary file from hdfs into a Spark dataframe?

Tags: python, hadoop, numpy, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to port some code from pandas to (py)Spark. Unfortunately I am already failing with the input part, where I want to read in binary data and put it in a Spark Dataframe.

So far I am using `fromfile` from numpy:

```
dt = np.dtype([('val1', '<i4'),('val2','<i4'),('val3','<i4'),('val4','f8')])
data = np.fromfile('binary_file.bin', dtype=dt)
data=data[1:]                                           #throw away header
df_bin = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.dtype.names)
```

But for Spark I couldn't find how to do it. My workaround so far was to use csv-Files instead of the binary file, but that is not an ideal solution. I am aware that I shouldn't use numpy's `fromfile` with spark. 
How can I read in a binary file that is already loaded into hdfs?

I tried something like

```
fileRDD=sc.parallelize(['hdfs:///user/bin_file1.bin','hdfs:///user/bin_file2.bin])
fileRDD.map(lambda x: ???)
```

But it is giving me a `No such file or directory` error.

I have seen this question:
[spark in python: creating an rdd by loading binary data with numpy.fromfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037615/spark-in-python-creating-an-rdd-by-loading-binary-data-with-numpy-fromfile)
but that only works if I have the files stored in the home of the driver node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, for anyone that starts with Spark as me and stumbles upon binary files. Here is how I solved it:

```
dt=np.dtype([('idx_metric','>i4'),('idx_resource','>i4'),('date','>i4'),
             ('value','>f8'),('pollID','>i2')])
schema=StructType([StructField('idx_metric',IntegerType(),False),
                   StructField('idx_resource',IntegerType(),False), 
                   StructField('date',IntegerType),False), 
                   StructField('value',DoubleType(),False), 
                   StructField('pollID',IntegerType(),False)])

filenameRdd=sc.binaryFiles('hdfs://nameservice1:8020/user/*.binary')

def read_array(rdd):
    #output=zlib.decompress((bytes(rdd[1])),15+32) # in case also zipped
    array=np.frombuffer(bytes(rdd[1])[20:],dtype=dt) # remove Header (20 bytes)
    array=array.newbyteorder().byteswap() # big Endian
    return array.tolist()

unzipped=filenameRdd.flatMap(read_array)
bin_df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(unzipped,schema)
```

And now you can do whatever fancy stuff you want in Spark with your dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
Please review the use of sc.binaryFiles as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28753276/5088142

---

try using:

```
hdfs://machine_host_name:8020/user/bin_file1.bin
```

you the host-name in **fs.defaultFS** in **core-site.xml**

Comment: fs.defaultFS says nameservice1, but also with `hdfs://nameservice1:8020/user/bin_file1.bin` I still get a file not found error.
Could it be linked with the function I put in the map?
`def read_bin:
    with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
        byte = f.read(1)
        while byte != "":
        byte = f.read(1)`

Comment: On which line do you get the "file not found error"? How do you plan to use the "read_bin" function? the open method doesn't seems to work with HDFS....

Comment: The error is on line 2 in read_bin. You are right, the open method doesn't like HDFS. 
I am looking for something similar to `sc.textfile(filename).map(lambda line:line.split(',')).map(lambda x: (int(x[0],int(x[1]....)`

Comment: Please review the use of sc.binaryFiles as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28753276/5088142

Answer (score 1):

*Since Spark 3.0, Spark supports binary file data source, which reads binary files and converts each file into a single record that contains the raw content and metadata of the file.*

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this:

```
from struct import unpack_from

# creates an RDD of binaryrecords for determinted record length
binary_rdd = sc.binaryRecords("hdfs://" + file_name, record_length)

# map()s each binary record to unpack() it
unpacked_rdd = binary_rdd.map(lambda record: unpack_from(unpack_format, record))

# registers a data frame with this schema; registerTempTable() it as table_name
raw_df = sqlc.createDataFrame(unpacked_rdd, sparkSchema)
raw_df.registerTempTable(table_name)
```

where unpack_format and sparkSchema have to be "in-sync".

- unpack_format is in format used by Python's unpack() and unpack_from() function as described in
  https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters
- sparkSchema is a variables that defines data frame's schema. See examples at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame

I have a script that generates unpack_format and sparkSchema variables dynamically; both at the same time. (it's part of a larger code-base, so not posting here for readbility)

unpack_format and sparkSchema could be defined as following, for example,

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

unpack_format = '<'   # '<' means little-endian: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment
sparkSchema = StructType()
record_length = 0

unpack_format += '35s'    # 35 bytes that represent a character string
sparkSchema.add("FirstName", 'string', True)  # True = nullable
record_length += 35

unpack_format += 'H'    # 'H' = unsigned 2-byte integer
sparkSchema.add("ZipCode", 'integer', True)
record_length += 2

# and so on for each field..
```